# VBA Syntax for properly formated output

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the following vba originally provided by RBarryYoung.  It's close but not quite there.

```
Sub quote()
' get the current selection
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Selection
If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Nothing Selected", vbOKOnly, "Cannot Define Local Name"
    Exit Sub
End If

' get the current worksheet
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = rng.Worksheet
Sht = ActiveSheet.Name
xps = "!"


' get the name to define
Dim sNam As String
sNam = InputBox("Enter the Name to Define for this Sheet:", "Define Local Name")
If sNam = "" Then Exit Sub

' define a name local to this worksheet
wks.Names.Add sNam, Sht & rng.Address

End Sub
```

The issue is that the local "refer to" definition isn't properly formatted.  It should be this

```
='VMware Servers'!$K$45
```

But the closest I've gotten is this:

```
="'VMware Servers'!$K$45"
```

And because of this, the value is off which breaks everything.